# showing Jquery ui datepicker on click of asp:linkbutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Can we show Jquery UI datepicker on click of asp.net linkbutton ?

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="PublishedSortLinkButton" runat="server"
                cssclass="datepicker"     Text="<%$ Resources:Vacancies, DateRange %>" CssClass="datepickerCompleted" />
```

and here is the Jquery

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            });
```

but it doesn't show jquery datepicker

I tried this:

```
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                $('#selec').click(function () {
                    $('#datepicker').toggle();
                });
```

Click

and it worked.

asp:LinkButton causes postback If that is the reason, I can use asp:hyperlink as well.

Comment: Confusing!!! Are using ID or class?? Once you used `$(".datepicker")` and next you used `$("#datepicker")`???

Comment: at one point i am using id as it is html control where as with asp:hyperlinkbutton, I am using class because  asp.net control's generated html makes id longer ( with appended master page and page name)

Comment: Ok got it. But you know that the datepicker can only be applied to `input type="text"` not to the asp LinkButtons or html rendered hyperlinks, right? Have you tried it with asp textbox or html `input type="text"` ?

Comment: @palaѕн I need to show it in header of asp.net gridview on click of a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("#datepicker").hide().datepicker()

$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Show the datepicker div
    $("#datepicker").toggle();
});
```

Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAprE/)

Comment: @palash what if i want to hide it when user clicks somehwere on page ?